# “Everything is predetermined” - Ramana Maharishi. Can someone please provide an explanation or sources which delve into this further?

Tags: karma, time, maya

Below is from one of the talks with Ramana Maharishi

Day by Day with Bhagavan”, Pg 78, (on 4.1.46, afternoon)]

“With reference to Bhagavan’s answer [above] to Mrs. Desai’s question on the evening of 3.1.46, I [Devaraja Mudaliar] asked Him, ‘Are only the important events in a man’s life, such as his main occupation or profession, predetermined, or are trifling acts in his life, such as taking a cup of water or moving from one place in the room to another, also predetermined?’

Bhagavan: “Yes, everything is predetermined”

I: ‘Then what responsibility, what free will has man?’

Bhagavan: “What for then does the body come into existence? It is designed for doing the various things marked out for execution in this life. The whole programme is chalked out. ‘Not an atom moves except by His Will’ expresses the same truth, whether you say ‘Does not move except by His Will’, or ‘Does not move except by karma’. As for freedom for man, he is always free not to identify himself with the body and not to be affected by the pleasures and pains consequent on the body’s activities.”

Today I was in the kitchen about to get a banana and I saw a fruit fly flying around it which I immediately killed. Later I thought and thought about this of whether it was “fruit fly’s” destiny to be killed by me or was that I executed my free will and killed it. If the latter is true then it means that I changed the destiny of something.

My question is:

1. If everything is predetermined then does striving for more moksha, knowledge etc. useless as it will only happen when the time arrives?
2. If Past/present/future is all predetermined then my Karmas should have not effect what so ever on the future.......so How is Karma intertwined with predeterminism?
3. Is there anything called free will or is it just an illusion?

Comment: = the way this Cosmos is projected to function is predetermined, and pre-destined from past life Karmas will affect your life. WHAT HAPPENS , HAPPENS FOR EVERYONE, BUT WHAT HAPPENS FOR YOU DECIDED BY YOU!

Comment: Read Swami Vivekananda's lecture called 'Vedantism' in Complete Works, Vol3, section 'Lectures from Colombo to Almora' here - https://advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php

Comment: Thank you Sawmi Ji. I also found one of the other answers you have posted on a similar other question which I found useful. Swami Ji so the creation remains the same but the souls in the bodies vary? I read your other answer where you have talked about the Ferris wheel of London where different people go in but the circle is the same. So does that mean Loosely that in the previous cycles there was another soul in my body?